# Re-creating a queue afters its manually deleted RabbitMQ

Tags: java, rabbitmq, queue

Is it possible to automatically re-create a queue afters it has been manually removed?

I'm able to create the queue on start up using

```
@Bean
public Queue createRandomQueue(@Qualifier("exporterRabbitAdmin") RabbitAdmin exporterRabbitAdmin) {
    Queue queue = createQueue("random.queue", exporterRabbitAdmin);
    exporterRabbitAdmin.declareQueue(queue);
    return queue;
}
```

However, if it's manually removed from rabbitmq, I want to be able to create a queue with the same name automatically.

Today if I remove it, I will keep throwing exceptions like

```
org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.BlockingQueueConsumer$DeclarationException: Failed to declare queue(s):[random.queue]
at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.BlockingQueueConsumer.attemptPassiveDeclarations(BlockingQueueConsumer.java:710) [spring-rabbit-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.BlockingQueueConsumer.passiveDeclarations(BlockingQueueConsumer.java:594) [spring-rabbit-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
at ....


Caused by: com.rabbitmq.client.ShutdownSignalException: channel error; protocol method: #method<channel.close>(reply-code=404, reply-text=NOT_FOUND - no queue 'export-hub-activity.retry.queue' in vhost 'default', class-id=50, method-id=10)
at com.rabbitmq.utility.ValueOrException.getValue(ValueOrException.java:66) ~[amqp-client-5.4.3.jar:5.4.3]
at com.rabbitmq.utility.BlockingValueOrException.uninterruptibleGetValue(BlockingValueOrException.java:36) ~[amqp-client-5.4.3.jar:5.4.3]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can re-create the queue which you have deleted. In RabbitMQ each operation is an event. When a queue is deleted, it is recorded as an event and these events can be consumed like normal messages.

You can enable RabbitMQ events by enabling the [rabbitmq_event_exchange](https://www.rabbitmq.com/event-exchange.html) plugin. Once it is set, bind it to a queue. While consuming the messages from the events-queue, you need to check for the message that contains `queue.deleted`. If there is any such message, you can re-create the queue. The `queue.deleted` event will also contain the `queue name` and the `virtual host`

Reference: https://www.rabbitmq.com/event-exchange.html

Answer (score 0):

For those interested:

I was using a different virtual host for my queues so I had to modify rabbitmq.config and add the following code before enabling the plugin

```
{rabbitmq_event_exchange, [{vhost, <<"default">>}]}
```

** the "default" here is my virtual host, the out of the box virtual host is "/"

Also I created a queue to listen to the exchange that the plugins creates

```
 @Bean
public Queue exporterRabbitMqEvents(RabbitAdmin rabbitAdmin) {
    Queue queue = createQueue("my_event_queue", rabbitAdmin);
    exporterRabbitAdmin.declareQueue(queue);

    Binding binding =
            new Binding("my_event_queue",
                    Binding.DestinationType.QUEUE,
                    "amq.rabbitmq.event", "queue.deleted", null);
    exporterRabbitAdmin.declareBinding(binding);

    return queue;
}
```

And finally created a listener to listen to "my_event_queue"  queue and dynamically recreate a queue if I got a queue.deleted event